# pass value of 2 divs in link_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text" id="qty" value="<%= item.quantity.to_i %>" min="0" step="1" style="width:50px;">


<%= link_to "+", { :controller => "orders", :action => "increase_item_quantity", :id => item.id, :amount => '$('qty').value' }, class: "ui button", style: "background-color:#2B4B6F;color:white;font-weight:bold;" %>
```

I have a link_to and i need to pass the value of the div id "qty" and am having trouble doing so. My code is obviously no good. How can i pass the extra param into the link to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it can be done with form.

But you can also use jQuery for the purpose:

```
$('#my-plus-link').click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  var url = $(this).attr('href')
  var qty = $('#qty').val()
  window.location = url + '&amount=' + qty
})
```

I assume, you have `id="my-plus-link"` for your add button.

Comment: This didn't work. My URL ends up like this: http://localhost:3000/increase_item_quantity?id=2 so amount is still not being passed in

Comment: @sump use `window.location = url + '&amount=' + qty` then

Comment: do i need to add remote: => true ?

Comment: do you have `id` on your link?

Comment: you might also need `evt.preventDefault` for this to work (see update)

Comment: <%= link_to "+", { :controller => "orders", :action => "increase_item_quantity", :id => item.id }, id: "my-plus-link", class: "ui button", style: "background-color:#2B4B6F;color:white;font-weight:bold;" %>

Comment: after adding evt.preventDefault the url is still: http://localhost:3000/increase_item_quantity?id=2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90753/discussion-between-dimakura-and-sump).